# Command Not Working With Shortcut Keys

Tags: shortcut-keys

I can run

```
xclip -s primary -o >> file1.txt
```

Fine in terminal, but running it with custom shortcut key nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@[Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek)* pointed out in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/825761/367990), the correct argument for `xclip` is `-selection` and not `-s`:

```
xclip -selection primary -o >> file1.txt
```

However this is not the only problem. Keyboard shortcuts do not run in a Bash shell, but you try to use output redirection (`>>`) here, which is a Bash feature.

Therefore you must explicitly run your shortcut command in a Bash shell to get the redirection to work:

```
bash -c 'xclip -selection primary -o >> file1.txt'
```

You should specify a full absolute path to the output file though. Not sure if it is necessary, but it would be better style anyway.

Comment: Well said!!!!!!

Comment: `sh` instead of `bash` would be leaner, more portable and work just as well.

Comment: That was a masterly reply Byte Commander, thank you.  But how did you know? I had looked everywhere and could not find a clue. Is the manual to blame? I suggest your reply should be added to the examples given in xclip manual   -- thanks again

Comment: I've had similar problems with assigning commands to shortcuts already. It is not `xclip`'s fault, it's just that keyboard shortcuts don't run in a shell so they may not contain shell specific stuff like output redirections.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once with putting something into the clipboard, so your question reminded me of that :)

My input into the command field of the shortcut definition:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo -n "Display: $DISPLAY" | xsel -b -i'
```

This successfully places the content of the Display variable into the clipboard.

My explanation at the time - not thought much about it - is that the program is called directly by the lightdm init process, so it gets no shell. And without a shell no shell redirection :)

So the quick fix is to give the command a shell.

Comment: This is what I already described in my answer.

Comment: Jeeze - look at the times - we where writing in parallel :))

Comment: I posted my answer more than 2 minutes before yours. The edit later did not add any new content. But it's okay, just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the -s switch is not being understood. From the man page.

```
-selection
              specify which X selection to use, options are "primary"  to  use
              XA_PRIMARY  (default),  "secondary"  for  XA_SECONDARY or "clip‐
              board" for XA_CLIPBOARD
 -version
              show version information

 -silent
              fork into the background to wait for requests, no  informational
              output, errors only (default)
```

Try the -selection switch instead.

Source `man xclip`